# Django api api/add/2/+/3 vs api/method=add&expression=2+3

Tags: python, django

What is the community accepted way of building an api using django? Using the format /xxx/method/whatever or using a php like syntax?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to specify both `add` and `+`? Why not `api/add/2/3` or `api/2+3`?

Comment: Your variation makes sense, however content was made on the fly, that's not the main point of the question, it could as easily have been xxx/fff vs method=xxx&value=fff

Comment: What about send all data as a json to be prepared to do some more complex computation too?

Comment: So, stop working in get/post and work with json instead? This api serves web apps and mobile apps. The replies will be json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing specific about making an API in django. [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) principles applies whatever web framework you used.

In short, there are 4 main HTTP verbs:

```
GET - for listing resources or retrieving details
POST - for creating resources
PUT - for replacing/updating resources
DELETE - for deleting resources
```

Query strings with GET should be used for search queries. For example:

1. Wolfram Alpha uses url-encoded string for querying about mathematical expression: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%2B3
2. Google uses url-encoded string for its search query: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=2%2B3

If your mathematical expression creates new resources, they should be sent in the POST body, usually either url-encoded or for more complex resources in JSON as XML. Likewise, with PUT for updating, and DELETE for deleting. The resources you need to create/update/delete should be identified by its URL.

If you want to support multiple formats (e.g. XML, JSON) or multiple languages of the same resource, you should use [Content Negotiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation). Also, following [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) principle is highly recommended, all URLs used within the service should be discoverable within the service itself, instead of having to be inferred from a separate documentation.